# Add New Line and Save in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Following the example below, I want to add a new line accordingly, and what I write in the four Textbox boxes (for Answers).

In the text file (Answer) the first word will always be empty space, and only after we start writing the words.

[image: IMG1]
  [image: IMG2]
  [image: IMG3]

Following the example below, I want to add a new line accordingly, and what I write in the four Textbox boxes (for Answers).

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data\Question.dat"))
        TextBox2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data\Answer.dat"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, here are two different ways of doing it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Output As String = TextBox1.Text
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:/Junk/Textfile1.txt", vbCrLf & Output, False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim OutputFile2 As System.IO.StreamWriter
        OutputFile2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:/Junk/Textfile2.txt", True)
        OutputFile2.WriteLine()
        OutputFile2.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        OutputFile2.Close()
    End Sub
```

Textbox1.text can replaced with a file location/name if you don't want to pull it into a textbox first.  I just did it this way because that looks like what you are currently doing.

Comment: Good. Looks like it works pretty well. Thx! I've adapted my needs code and looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but if you need to add a blank line before the content of your input file, you can use something like this:

```
textbox1.text=vbcrlf & System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data\Question.dat"))
```

Comment: Need a write line.

Comment: Instead of concatenating, use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)